# SQL Server Management Studio Express - include date/time in Results or Messages

Tags: date-time, query, sql-management-studio

In SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005 is it possible to output the date and time that a query completed in the Results or Messages windows?

(without having to manually add a `SELECT Getdate()` to every query)

Comment: I looked through the options and there's nothing that looks like the IDE can do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to 2008 version which has a `Properties` panel which includes the `Connection finish time` - this is exactly what I need!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is only part of what you are looking for, but if you turn on the Include Client Statistics option, you'll get a new Client Statistics tab when you run your query that will include the time the query was run.  It's under Query>Include Client Statistics.

Comment: I'll try this when I'm back at work tomorrow AM

Comment: which version of SQL Management Tools are you using? I can't find that option anywhere in 2005 and the Help does not shed any light.

Comment: @Shevek - I'm using 2008, my apologies for not specifying that in my response.  I'm glad that you were able to solve your problem.